# Bangla Font is not showing in ubuntu .net6

Tags: c#, itext, ubuntu-18.04, asp.net-core-6.0

At windows, the font is showing perfectly but at ubuntu is showing as the box. I have attached both pdf.

1. Windows one
   [image: windows]
2. Ubuntu One
   [image: Linux]

I use iTextSharp for PDF and the address itself is an image.

Here is the code

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(shippingAddressData.Address1))
                    {
                        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(shippingAddressData.Address2))
                        {
                            var customercityStateZipCountry = await FormatAddressTextAsync(shippingAddressData);
                            shippingAddress1 = shippingAddress1 + indent + "Address: " + shippingAddressData.Address1 + customercityStateZipCountry;
                        }
                        var customerAddress1Split = Split(shippingAddress1, 43);
                        int i = 0;
                        foreach (var customerAddress1BreakDown in customerAddress1Split)
                        {
                            if (i == 0)
                            {
                                var customerAddress1InBitMap = ConvertToBitMapDefault(customerAddress1BreakDown, 22f);
                                Image customerAddress1InImage = Image.GetInstance(customerAddress1InBitMap, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                                shippingAddressPDF.AddCell(customerAddress1InImage);


                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var secondLine = indent + customerAddress1BreakDown;
                                var customerAddress1InBitMap = ConvertToBitMapDefault(secondLine, 22f);
                                Image customerAddress1InImage = Image.GetInstance(customerAddress1InBitMap, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                                shippingAddressPDF.AddCell(customerAddress1InImage);
                            }
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
```

The supporting method

```
public System.Drawing.Bitmap ConvertToBitMapDefault(string Text, float fontSize = 22f, int widthPoint = 0)
        {
            //string familyName = _fileProvider.Combine(_fileProvider.MapPath("~/App_Data/Pdf/"), "ARIALUNI.ttf");
            //Path.Combine(CommonHelper.MapPath("~/App_Data/Pdf/"), "ARIALUNI.ttf");
            string familyName = _fileProvider.Combine(_fileProvider.MapPath("~/App_Data/Pdf/"), _pdfSettings.FontFileName);

            System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(850, 40, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            bitmap.SetResolution(500f, 200f);
            System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage((System.Drawing.Image)bitmap);
            graphics.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            graphics.DrawString(Text ?? "", new System.Drawing.Font(familyName, fontSize, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular), System.Drawing.SystemBrushes.InfoText,
                (System.Drawing.PointF)new System.Drawing.Point(widthPoint, 3));

            return bitmap;
        }
```

Comment: Check if you are able to resolve the font in both OS.. What's the value of familyName coming? Is that font by default available in underlying OS?

Comment: the value of famiyName is FreeSerif.ttf

Comment: Is that font by default available in the underlying OS?

Comment: I tried other fonts also but no luck.

Comment: You can try my solution, if not work, pls let me know.

Comment: inspect this new System.Drawing.Font(familyName, fontSize, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular) in both windows and linux os to see the difference in object and you will be able to solve issue

Answer (score 0):

Please encode characters in your code by using `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode`, like below. It works for me and it should useful to you.

```
string Address1= shippingAddressData.Address1;
Address1 = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Address1, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
```

Comment: I must try and let you know here In Sha Allah.

Comment: No not work. It is showing white rather than printing anything.

Comment: @sina_Islam Can you debug it, and share the content for us, we need check the format in your server side. Because we are not sure the issue in server side or client side.

Comment: sure I will debug and share here.